# ¿Cómo ejecutar un archivo .java desde nuestro propio código java?

Tags: java, ant

He tenido esta duda desde siempre, y he buscado esa información desde internet pero no he logrado solventar esa duda. Quisiera tomar un archivo .java y poder compilarlo desde mi propio código java (no se si me explique). Sin nada más, muchas gracias.

Comment: Y qué tal si usas la consola del sistema.

Comment: Un script para compilar el .java?  O después  vas a usar el archivo compilado en el mismo programa. Como indicó @Daniel Briceño podrias ejecutar comandos de la consola desde la aplicación java.

Comment: Lo segundo que comentaste @LucasRox

Comment: Oh bien, tratar de tomar ciertos archivos de un .zip y base a eso, usar ANT dentro de mi mismo programa y compilar lo que tenga ese zip.

Comment: Si lo quieres ejecutar: [Como usar la consola del sistema para ejecutar java](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=395:compilar-y-ejecutar-un-programa-java-uso-de-la-consola-dos-o-cmd-de-windows-invocar-javac-cu00612b&catid=68&Itemid=188),,,  [Como usar java para aceder a la consola del sistema](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/como-ejecutar-un-comando-del-sistema-desde-java/)